# MongoDB - Why my multikey index is not used in facet?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am having trouble understanding why an index is not able to cover a certain query, when my interpretation of documentation suggests it should... :)

The document I am referring to is: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/

I am creating an index on a property which is part of an array of objects. The value indexed is present in other documents. The query looks up directly for the value of the property in the array. But when I look at the plan in the profiler, it is looking through the entire collection.

The structure of the document is as follows:

```json
{
    "userEmail": "string",
    "basicInformation": {
       "name" : "string"
    },
   "events":  {
        "live" : [
              {"eventId": "id of event 1",    // <--- field indexed : "events.live.eventId"
               "date" : "date of event",
              "duration": n},
              {"eventId": "id of event 2",
               "date" : "date of event",
              "duration": n},
              ...
         ],
   "onDemand" : [
              {"eventId": "id of event 1",  // <--- field indexed : "events.onDemand.eventId"
               "date" : "date of event",
              "duration": n},
              {"eventId": "id of event 2",
               "date" : "date of event",
              "duration": n},
              ...
         ]


    }
```

QUERY:

```
{
     $facets: {
       "liveUsers": [
            {$match: {"events.live.eventId": "id of event 1"}},
           { $project: { .... }}
      ],
        "onDemandUsers": [
            {$match: {"events.live.eventId": "id of event 1"}},
           { $project: { .... }}
      ]
    }
}

}
```

The plan does not seem to use the index and scans the collection. Currently the number of documents in the collection is over 63K, which leads to alerts. Can you help me understand how the indexes should be built or query restructured, so that we can avoid the full collection scan.

Comment: its the `$facet` see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#index-use) it cannot use the index, but you probably can re-write the query without the facet

Comment: Thank you @Takis_ for the response. I used facets to avoid extra calls to get the same base data. The follow up question would be, should I move the filters up in the aggregation or break into two queries?

Comment: It looks like both facets use the same match criteria.  Have you tried putting that in a `$match` stage before the `$facet` stage?

Comment: Please provide your index definitions on this collection